# Wrong fonts and wrong autofit when using Syncfusion's ExcelToPdfConverter

Tags: excel, pdf, fonts, syncfusion

I am currently using Syncfusion's `ExcelToPdfConverter` to convert an XLSX document to a PDF.

I first create the XLSX document and then convert it to PDF with the following code:

```
var converter = new ExcelToPdfConverter(workbook);
//Intialize the PDFDocument
var pdfDoc = new PdfDocument();
//Intialize the ExcelToPdfconverterSettings
var settings = new ExcelToPdfConverterSettings();
//Assign the PDFDocument to the TemplateDocument property of ExcelToPdfConverterSettings
settings.TemplateDocument = pdfDoc;
settings.EmbedFonts = true;
//Convert Excel Document into PDF document
pdfDoc = converter.Convert(settings);
//Save the pdf file
pdfDoc.Save(PDFFullPath);
```

The resulting XLSX is correct and it looks like it should. 
The converted PDF isn't correct though. It's just like it's using wrong fonts and, as a consequence, those rows that have been autofitted with `AutofitRow` get truncated.

Has anyone else had this issue before?
Is there any way to tell the `PDFConverter` to use the correct fonts? (Please note that I'm using Arial and Calibri and they're both installed in the system's fonts)

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was actually a bug in Syncfusion XlsIO that has been fixed in a patch due out in February 2017.
The above code is correct.

Answer (score 0):

We suspect that the issue might occur due to the assignment of wrong row index. In XlsIO, the Row and Column indexes are one based.

Kindly refer below documentation to know more about AutofitRow and AutofitColumn.

Documentation Link: https://help.syncfusion.com/file-formats/xlsio/worksheet-rows-and-columns-manipulation#auto-fit-a-single-row-or-column

Regards,

Abirami.

Comment: This has been fixed by you guys at SyncFusion a few days ago. It was actually a bug.